# Jenkins запуск докера

Tags: jenkins, devops

Такой вопрос:
Я собрал докер образ, в jenkins при сборке образа я добавляю переменную $Build и делаю push на docker hub.

Далее в этой же таски я пишу баш скрипт:
ssh root@1.1.1.1 'docker pull name.27 && docker run -d -p 80:80 name.27 '
который запускает докер на удаленном сервере.
Цифра 27 это номер билда.

Как передать ему номер билда на удаленный сервер чтобы он автомато при сборке разворачивал докер образ.
Через переменную не хочет.
Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо использовать переменные среды Jenkins'a.

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625259/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-jenkins) пару вариантов, как все это сделать.

Вот [тут](https://medium.com/@gustavo.guss/jenkins-building-docker-image-and-sending-to-registry-64b84ea45ee9) детально как использовать docker вместе с Jenkims'ом.